# Git: Undo local changes since failed merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I've gotten myself into a situation that seems fairly unusual, and essentially want to split my working state into two commits. One is a merge commit and the other is a substantial commit of its own.

**Here's what went down:**

1. I saved my working state with `git stash`
2. `git rebase master`
3. See some merge conflicts, fix them
4. `git stash pop`
5. Work for a while on the files with conflicts

Notice that I forgot to commit the fix for the merge conflicts, so those files are still marked as conflicted. But they also have local changes that I don't want.

## The goal

One commit to resolve the merge conflicts, and one commit with my local changes. How can I split my current (conflicted) state into these two commits?

Comment: @Michael Updated to ask a clearer question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution, which worked because my changes were separate chunks in the diff.  Here's what I did:

1. `git add` all the unmerged files, which brought my working tree into a usable state
2. `git reset` to unstage those files
3. Choose specific chunks to commit with `git add --patch`

The downside of this solution is that the first commit does not have any automatic metadata about the merge conflict that caused it.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, and not having a repo in a similar state to play with, the best plan is probably to `git stash` the current state (merge in progress plus new work), then `git reset` back to before the merge. Redo the merge then, and remember to commit. Then `git stash pop`, but you'll probably end up with the inverse of the merge conflicts to sort out when you do that.

Unless you can specifically pick apart the chunks that came from the merge vs. your additional work via `git add -i` et. al., or if either the merge or the additional work are insignificant enough to toss and start over...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately `git stash` actually fails due to the unresolved conflicts. Do you think it matters if I add the files before stashing?

Comment: @Wylie That might allow `git stash` to succeed. Alternatively, you could possibly toss the merge results on just those files (unless some of your additional work is in the same files) with `git reset` so they don't appear to be merge-in-progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `git rebase --abort` (since you are doing a rebase), a `git stash` again, and then trying to `git rebase` again, and solving the conflicts with `git mergetool`. When you are done with the conflicts, `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: In the documentation for `git rebase --abort` I see that it will attempt to restore the state to what it was before the commit. How will that affect my changes since?

Comment: Oh. This is more difficult than I thought. Try to `git stash` before you make the `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: `git stash` fails due to the merge conflicts, which seems to be a limitation of the tool

Comment: Resolve the conflicts with `git mergetool`. Then `git stash`. When you are finally prepared to commit, use `git commit -p`, which will allow you to commit only parts of the file.